# $(0,1)-$normalization of a cooperative game

Tags: real-numbers, game-theory

Let $v:2^{\{1,2,3\}}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a characteristic function game given by

$   v(S)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  -2 \qquad\text{ if $S$ has 1 member}\\
                   \ \ \ 2 \qquad\text{ if $S$ has 2 members}\\
                   \ \ \ 0 \qquad\text{ if $S$ has 3 members}\\
                \end{array}
              \right.
 $

How do I compute its the strategically equivalent $(0,1)-$normalized game ?
A game $v$ is $(0,1)-$normalized if $v(N)=1$ and $v(\{i\})=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

$$\frac{v(S)-\sum_{i\in S}v(\{i\})}{v(N)-\sum_{i\in N}v(\{i\})}$$